# CPP, 'X' button listener

Tags: c++, windows

I'm writing a CPP program, and I want to execute a function when the 'X'(shut down) button is pressed.

For example, I have an infinite loop that prints the same thing everytime it iterates, until the 'X' button is pressed, and I want to execute a function before the process ends.

Is there some kind of listener for this matter? Or some other solution maybe (like delaying the process shut down for a few seconds or something)?

Thanks!

Comment: What platform/OS, and console or graphical UI?  Almost every platform uses [X] to close a window.

Comment: @RichardCritten Hey, Im using Windows 7 as my OS, and simply Visual Studio 2012, a simple cpp program, no GUI or anything.

Comment: You mean a win32 console application? A window is not necessary so the X button may not exist.

Comment: @drescherjm yeah, a win32 console app, i just want to execute a function before the process ends, is that possible by any way?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute something before your process ends, you can register an [std::atexit](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/atexit) handler. This function will be called before your process exits.